# HTML5 anchor download filename not working

Tags: html

I have an anchor tag like this..

```
<a class="btn btn-download" href="https://www.anotherdomain.com/file.jpg" download="customname.jpg">Download</a>
```

it is downloading as file.jpg and NOT customname.jpg

It works if the file is in the same domain

```
<a class="btn btn-download" href="/file.jpg" download="customname.jpg">Download</a>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything, that's how it works. The [**doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) on MDN says:

> This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

However, this is not specified in W3C specs, currently it depends on the browser venders.

For Firefox, you could take a look at [**this issue**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619) to get a clue of how it was turned off intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

If the download attribute is not supported then it falls back to the file name. I think only chrome and Firefox support the download attribute, could it be a browser issue? Documentation from the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html) does not specify any issues with cross-domain file downloads.